# How to launch two threads in bash shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp, multithreading

I am trying to copy files from `machineB` and `machineC` into `machineA` as I am running my below shell script on `machineA`.

If the files is not there in `machineB` then it should be there in `machineC` for sure so I will try copying the files from `machineB` first, if it is not there in `machineB` then I will try copying the same files from `machineC`.

I am copying the files in parallel using GNU Parallel library and it is working fine. Currently I am copying two files in parallel.

Currently, I am copying the `PRIMARY_PARTITION` files in `PRIMARY` folder using GNU parallel and once that is done, then I copy the `SECONDARY_PARTITION` files in `SECONDARY` folder using same GNU parallel so it is sequential as of now w.r.t `PRIMARY` and `SECONDARY` folder

Below is my shell script and everything works fine -

```
#!/bin/bash

export PRIMARY=/test01/primary
export SECONDARY=/test02/secondary
readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
export FILERS_LOCATION_1=${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}
export FILERS_LOCATION_2=${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(550 274 2 546 278) # this will have more file numbers
SECONDARY_PARTITION=(1643 1103 1372 1096 1369) # this will have more file numbers

export dir3=/testing/snapshot/20140103

# delete primary files first and then copy
find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_CopyInPrimary() {
  el=$1
  scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
}
export -f do_CopyInPrimary
parallel -j 2 do_CopyInPrimary ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"

# delete secondary files first and then copy
find "$SECONDARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_CopyInSecondary() {
  el=$1
  scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/. || scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/.
}
export -f do_CopyInSecondary
parallel -j 2 do_CopyInSecondary ::: "${SECONDARY_PARTITION[@]}"
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Is there any way I can launch two threads, one to copy files in `PRIMARY` folder using the same setup as I have above, meaning it will copy two files in parallel. And second thread to copy the files in `SECONDARY` folder using the same setup as I have above, it should also copy two files parallel simultaneously?

Meaning they should copy files in parallel both in `PRIMARY` and `SECONDARY` folder simultaneously not once `PRIMARY` folder is done, then copy files in `SECONDARY` folder.

Currently, once `PRIMARY` folder file is done, then only I try copying the files in `SECONDARY` folder.

In short, I just need to launch two threads one thread will run this -

```
# delete primary files first and then copy
find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_CopyInPrimary() {
  el=$1
  scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
}
export -f do_CopyInPrimary
parallel -j 2 do_CopyInPrimary ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
```

And second thread will run this -

```
# delete secondary files first and then copy
find "$SECONDARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_CopyInSecondary() {
  el=$1
  scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/. || scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/.
}
export -f do_CopyInSecondary
parallel -j 2 do_CopyInSecondary ::: "${SECONDARY_PARTITION[@]}"
```

And once all the files are copied successfully, it should echo the message, that all the files are copied. In java, I know how to launch two threads and each thread is performing certain task but not sure how in bash shell script this will work?

My main task is to copy two files in parallel using GNU parallel in `PRIMARY` folder and `SECONDARY` folder at a same time?

Is this possible to do in bash shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious is:

```
parallel -j 2 do_CopyInPrimary ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}" &
parallel -j 2 do_CopyInSecondary ::: "${SECONDARY_PARTITION[@]}" &
wait
```

But this way the secondary does not wait for the primary to finish and it does not check if the primary was successful. Let us assume that $PRIMARY_PARTITION[1] corresponds to $SECONDARY_PARTITION[1] (so if you cannot read the file from 
$PRIMARY_PARTITION[1] you will read it from $SECONDARY_PARTITION[1] - That also means that $PRIMARY_PARTITION and $SECONDARY_PARTITION have the same number of elements). Then you can condition the running of $SECONDARY_PARTITION[1] on $PRIMARY_PARTITION[1].

```
do_Copy() {
  PRIMARY_PARTITION=(550 274 2 546 278) # this will have more file numbers
  SECONDARY_PARTITION=(1643 1103 1372 1096 1369) # this will have more file numbers
  pel=${PRIMARY_PARTITION[$1]}
  sel=${SECONDARY_PARTITION[$1]}
  do_CopyInPrimary $pel || 
    do_CopyInSecondary $sel || 
    echo Could not copy neither $pel nor $sel
}
export -f do_Copy
# Number of elements in PRIMARY_PARTITION == SECONDARY_PARTITION
seq ${#PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]} | parallel -j 2 do_Copy
```

This will get the dependency right, but it will only copy 2 at a time in total. With `-j4` you risk running 4 primaries at the same time, so we need to guard against that, too:

```
do_Copy() {
  PRIMARY_PARTITION=(550 274 2 546 278) # this will have more file numbers
  SECONDARY_PARTITION=(1643 1103 1372 1096 1369) # this will have more file numbers
  pel=${PRIMARY_PARTITION[$1]}
  sel=${SECONDARY_PARTITION[$1]}
  sem -j2 --fg --id primary do_CopyInPrimary $pel || 
    sem -j2 --fg --id secondary do_CopyInSecondary $sel || 
    echo Could not copy neither $pel nor $sel
}
export -f do_Copy
# Number of elements in PRIMARY_PARTITION == SECONDARY_PARTITION
seq ${#PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]} | parallel -j 4 do_Copy
```

`sem` will limit the number of primaries to 2 and the number of secondaries to 2.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In your suggestion, you said `Let us assume that $PRIMARY_PARTITION[1] corresponds to $SECONDARY_PARTITION[1].` What does this mean? And also in your last code example, you are passing `PRIMARY_PARTITION` array only? It does not take `SECONDARY_PARTITION` array I guess? Or may be I misunderstood some part of your answer?

Comment: Thanks for edit. I should have been more clear, sorry about that. In my case, number of elements in `PRIMARY_PARTITION` might be different as compared to `SECONDARY_PARTITION`. It will not be same at all. In this case, then how would I do that?

Answer (score 13):

Bash doesn't support threading, but it does support background multi-processing. That is, the process is cloned into a new process space, with its own environment, working directory, etc, and all communication has to happen through normal IPC channels. But otherwise it looks a lot like threading.

You do this by "backgrounding" a code block. Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    echo "Foo"
    sleep 1
    echo "Foo: done"
}&    
echo "Bar"
sleep 1
echo "Bar: done"
```

*output*

```
Bar
Foo
**[1 second delay]**
Bar: done
Foo: done
```

You can get the same effect by wrapping a code block in a function, and running that function as a background job.

Alternately, you can wrap your code block in parentheses instead of braces. Statements in parentheses explicitly (and always) run in a separate process; normally statements in braces are grouped but run without forking. Running the code in the background by using the `&` suffix forces that code to run in a separate process.

Comment: Just what I need. This is perfect for running a cron job every 30 seconds - one code block calls yoru script and the other sleeps for 30 seconds then calls the same script.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to use rsync instead of scp for this.  By copying all the files in one command instead of running scp for each file, it will save you a lot of time and effort, and will help ensure the data is copied correctly.  It also will skip copying existing files from machineC.  Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

files="one two three"
machines="machineB machineC"

for machine in machines
do
    ssh $machine -c "cd source_directory || exit 1; rsync -avPz --ignore-existing $files machineA:/receive_directory/"
done
```

Comment: You've changed the logic: each file should be copied from machineB if present and from machineC otherwise, but your script instead copies or not based on dates (and if you change the options to rsync, you'll still not be able to make the copy from machineC depend on the presence of the file on machineB).

Comment: If the files on `machineC` are newer than the files on `machineB`, you'd be correct, but if the timestamps are the same, or if the files on `machineB` are newer, you'd be incorrect.  Either way, the `--ignore-existing` rsync option would prevent a file from being recopied from `machineC` if it was already copied from `machineB`.  Its man page says, "--ignore-existing       skip updating files that exist on receiver," so it would make the copy from `machineC` depend entirely on the presence of the file on `machineB`.  I've added `--ignore-existing` to the answer; thanks.